# Removing strings after in a dataframe to make group

Tags: r

This is my set of col name which i want to make group.

```
colnames(data4)
[1] "VC_1_UI_S3"       "VC_2_UI_S4"       "BAF60A_KD_1_S13"  "BAF60A_KD_2_S14"  "VC_VD3_1_S7"      "VC_VD3_2_S8"     
[7] "BAF60A_VD3_1_S15" "BAF60A_VD3_2_S16"
```

Im doing this

```
metadata$Group <- sub("_[^[:alpha:]]+_S[0-9]", "", (colnames(data4)))

Which results in this

metadata
                       Group
VC_1_UI_S3        VC_1_UI_S3
VC_2_UI_S4        VC_2_UI_S4
BAF60A_KD_1_S13   BAF60A_KD3
BAF60A_KD_2_S14   BAF60A_KD4
VC_VD3_1_S7           VC_VD3
VC_VD3_2_S8           VC_VD3
BAF60A_VD3_1_S15 BAF60A_VD35
BAF60A_VD3_2_S16 BAF60A_VD36
```

For VC_VD3_1_S7 and VC_VD3_1_S8 Im getting the desired result which is only VC_VD3 but not for others so what I require is like this below

```
                    Group
VC_1_UI_S3        VC_1_UI
VC_2_UI_S4        VC_2_UI
BAF60A_KD_1_S13   BAF60A_KD
BAF60A_KD_2_S14   BAF60A_KD
VC_VD3_1_S7           VC_VD
VC_VD3_2_S8           VC_VD
BAF60A_VD3_1_S15 BAF60A_VD3
BAF60A_VD3_2_S16 BAF60A_VD3
```

Any suggestion or help really appreciated

Comment: why do you need the 3 at the end  in `BAF60A_VD3` from `BAF60A_VD3_1_S15` but not the 3 in `VC_VD3_1_S7`? Either you need it or you dont

Comment: VC_VD3_1_S7 for this i need to be like this VC_VD3 and for this BAF60A_VD3_1_S15 I need this  BAF60A_VD3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex making the number before `S[0-9]+` optional -

```
sub("_(\\d+_)?S[0-9]+$", "", x)

#[1] "VC_1_UI"    "VC_2_UI"  "BAF60A_KD"  "BAF60A_KD"  "VC_VD3"     "VC_VD3"    
#[7] "BAF60A_VD3" "BAF60A_VD3"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("VC_1_UI_S3" , "VC_2_UI_S4" ,"BAF60A_KD_1_S13" ,"BAF60A_KD_2_S14" ,
        "VC_VD3_1_S7","VC_VD3_2_S8", "BAF60A_VD3_1_S15", "BAF60A_VD3_2_S16")
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
sub("_\\d*_*S[0-9]+$", "", x)
#[1] "VC_1_UI"    "VC_2_UI"    "BAF60A_KD"  "BAF60A_KD"  
#[5]"VC_VD3"     "VC_VD3"     "BAF60A_VD3" "BAF60A_VD3"
```

---

Or use `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "_\\d*_*S[0-9]+$")
```

#### data

```
x <- c("VC_1_UI_S3", "VC_2_UI_S4", "BAF60A_KD_1_S13", "BAF60A_KD_2_S14", 
"VC_VD3_1_S7", "VC_VD3_2_S8", "BAF60A_VD3_1_S15", "BAF60A_VD3_2_S16"
)
```

Comment: this will also go into my code  along with the upper solution